# Getting Error with HttpClient Module in angular

Tags: angular, httpclient, ng-modules

> ERROR in node_modules/@angular/common/http/http.d.ts:81:22 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule class.

This likely means that the library (`@angular/common/http`) which declares `HttpClient` has not been processed correctly by `ngcc`, or
is not compatible with `Angular Ivy`. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.

81 export declare class HttpClient {

Comment: {
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "ngcc"
  }
}

Answer (score 30):

Maybe you have imported `HttpClient` instead of`HttpClientModule`.
Check imports in `app.module.ts`

```
imports: [  
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    FlexLayoutModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
```

Answer (score 5):

That precisely is, when it comes to importing it should be `HttpClientModule` and when it comes to usage it should be `HttpClient`

Reference: https://angular.io/guide/http

Answer (score 2):

1. `npm cache verify`
2. `npm cache clean --force`

Answer (score 1):

I faced Same Issue in AngularJs Version 13:

```
Error: node_modules/@angular/common/http/http.d.ts:91:22 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule class

This likely means that the library (@angular/common/http) which declares HttpClient has not been processed correctly by ngcc, or is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.
```

**Solution :** That Error is Our **HttpClientModule** is Not Import In our

> **app.module.ts** file

Then You Can Add **HttpClientModule** to imports Area.
*

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  // After import here Above Import API
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
It's working to me.

Finish serve project to : `Crtl+c`, `npm install`
and build again
`ng serve --open`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I just ran the following command and it worked for me.

```
npm cache verify
```

If it doesn't work, manually delete `node_module` and reinstall it.

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```

And also you need to add `HttpClientModule` just after `BrowserModule`. Otherwise, it won't work. See below.

```
imports: [  
   BrowserModule,
   HttpClientModule,
   AppRoutingModule,
   BrowserAnimationsModule,
   MatToolbarModule,
   FlexLayoutModule
],
```

Answer (score 0):

In app.module.ts => import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

In the service => import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

Answer (score 0):

The HttpClientModule needs to be imported under @NgModule section. So make sure it is under "imports" as opposed to the "declaration" section. This should resolve the problem as in: imports: [
BrowserModule,
**HttpClientModule,**
FormsModule,
AppRoutingModule,
],

Answer (score 0):

I made it work!

1. At app.module.ts, add **HttpClientModule** import, not **HttpClient**

`import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';`

2. At app.module.ts, add **HttpClientModule** in **imports** section

`

```
imports: [  
BrowserModule,
AppRoutingModule,
FormsModule,
HttpClientModule
  ],
```

`

3. At the **service.ts, do not import **HttpClientModule**. add **HttpClient** import instead.

`import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';`

I hope this is clear now!

Comment: Welcome to SO and thanks for sharing. This answer seems to be the same as the other existing answers here. Going forward, try to help improve existing answers instead of creating duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to run the following command

```
npm install
```