# Unable to process HttpClient in Angular 10

Tags: angular, httpclient, angular10

When I try to do `ng build` , I get an error saying

```
ERROR in node_modules/@angular/common/http/http.d.ts:81:22 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule class.

This likely means that the library (@angular/common/http) which declares HttpClient has not been processed correctly by ngcc, or is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.

81 export declare class HttpClient {
```

I try to delete the `node_modules` and reinstall it by `ng install`. I have even tried `npm ci` since I saw that as a solution at some other blog post, but none worked for me.

Here's my output for `ng version`

```
Angular CLI: 10.1.2
Node: 14.11.0
OS: darwin x64

Angular: 10.1.2
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1001.2
@angular-devkit/build-angular   0.1001.2
@angular-devkit/core            10.1.2
@angular-devkit/schematics      10.1.2
@schematics/angular             10.1.2
@schematics/update              0.1001.2
rxjs                            6.6.3
typescript                      4.0.3
```

My `AppModule` looks like this

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http'
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http'

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { SocketService } from "./socket.service";

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpClient,
        HttpClientModule
    ],
    providers: [SocketService],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: First run this command `npm audit fix -f`, then run `npm update`

Comment: @RajatSingh have you imported `HttpClientModule` in app.module.ts

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting Error with HttpClient Module in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61093935/getting-error-with-httpclient-module-in-angular)

Comment: @Abhishek let me try, also, I have added by `app.module.ts`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the `HttpClient` is a service, not a module to be imported, remove that from your imports array.

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule
],
```